# Whats wrong with my eventBus implementation?

Tags: vue.js, quasar, event-bus

I want to trigger a function from another component which is not parents and child relationship. i try to use eventbus, but i am not sure am i implemented it correctly, since the function is not working. i have created a boot file eventBus.js and added it into the quasar config, but its still not working. Anyone can help me to check which part did i implemented wrongly?

```
eventBus.js
import Vue from 'vue'

const eventBus = new Vue();

export default eventBus

Vue.prototype.$eventBus = eventBus;
```

below is the function that i want to get from this page, (this.getSchedule(), it is working perfectly on current page).

```
mounted(){
    this.$eventBus.$on("refreshListSchedule", ()=>{

      scheduleDate = this.scheduleDate
      console.log(scheduleDate)
      console.log("Testing successed")
      this.getSchedule()
    })
},
```

The page that i want to trigger it

```
this.$eventBus.$emit('refreshListSchedule')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you manually import from `eventBus.js` in each component where you want to emit or subscribe for events - don't rely on Vue.prototype.

And don't forget to unsubscribe in the `beforeDestroy` hook.

Comment: Hi @IVO GELOV thanks for your reply, yes i also tried this approach yesterday but it's still not working, not sure what cause it not functioning since i am new to eventBus, I also tried the quasar version https://quasar.dev/options/global-event-bus. Its there any mistake i have made in my code or eventbus implementation?

Comment: We can not see why it does not work unless you provide a CodeSandbox example.

Comment: Thanks IVO for trying to help, i revised through the documentation carefully and i dont think the eventbus work on two totally difference page of component. So i do it another way round by using the local storage event listener to trigger back the refresh function.

Comment: IF by `totally different page` you mean that the 2 components are not alive at the same time - then yes, the event emitted by component A won't reach component B (which is not yet instantiated). In this case you will have to use Vuex instead of event bus.